# Execute lambda function

Tags: python, lambda

I need to create a variable that uses a yet undefined variable, to share the code across children that will know the value. I was hoping to achieve this with lambda, but lambda does not get executed.

```
>>> a = "{0}{1}".format("abc", lambda: y)
>>> y = "def"
>>> a
'abc<function <lambda> at 0x7f3ee178b6a8>'
```

Why is lambda not executed and how do I get to execute in this situation? Many thanks.

Comment: Even if the lambda was executed, it would be executed in that first line, as part of the `format` call. `y` doesn't exist at that time either…

Comment: If anything, you want that entire string formatting to happen in a function which you explicitly call: `a = lambda: '{0}{1}'.format('abc', y); ... a()`

Answer (score 1):

Why not do:

```
a = lambda x: f"abc{x}"
y = "def"
a(y)  # Outputs 'abcdef'
```

And then you can just pass any variable you want to `a`?

Comment: Why answer a question with a question?

Comment: This does what you seem to want - the question is a request that you make yourself clearer. Is this working for you, or is there some hidden reason which forces you to do things like you tried to?